# Why the toggle in z-index is not working in class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6, sass

When i Use getelementbyID it is working but when I use the classname then it is not working. My instructor prefers using a class instead of ID. Sorry for my bad english.

```
/**
 * Move the nav__links on the backwards first
 */

const links = document.getElementsByClassName('.nav__links');
const btn = document.getElementsByClassName('.nav__btn');
const container = document.getElementsByClassName('.container');
const slider = document.getElementsByClassName('.slider');

btn.onclick = () => {
  links.style.zIndex = links.style.zIndex === '999' ? '' : '999';
  container.style.zIndex = container.style.zIndex === '-999' ? '' : '-999';
  slider.style.zIndex = slider.style.zIndex === '-999' ? '' : '-999';
}
```

this is the code for the slider

```
div.container__main
  div.slider
    div.slider__cell
      img.slider__cell--img(src='./img/img__slider.jpg' alt='banner1')
      img.slider__cell--img-sp(src='./img/img__slider-sp.jpg' 
      alt='banner1')
     div.slider__cell
      img.slider__cell--img(src='./img/img__slider.jpg' alt='banner2')
      img.slider__cell--img-sp(src='./img/img__slider-sp.jpg' alt='banner2')
     div.slider__cell
      img.slider__cell--img(src='./img/img__slider.jpg' alt='banner3')
      img.slider__cell--img-sp(src='./img/img__slider-sp.jpg' alt='banner3')
```

this is the code for the nav__btn

```
 header.nav
 div.nav__logo
   a(href='#')
   img.nav__logo(src="./img/header_logo.png", alt="logo")
 div.nav__icon-container
   input#nav__btn.nav__btn(type='checkbox')
   label.nav__icon(for='nav__btn')
     span.nav__icon--line
   ul#nav__links.nav__links
     li.nav__links--white
       div.nav__search 
         input.nav__search-box(type="text" placeholder="検索")
         button.nav__search-btn(type='button')
           img(src="./img/search_btn.png", alt="search btn")
     li.nav__links--link
       a.nav__item(href="#") お知らせ
```

This is the code for nav__links

```
&__links {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
list-style: none;
@include sp {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
  top: getsp375(90px);
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 45px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  font-size: getsp375(14px);
  text-align: left;
  transition: opacity 0.8s 0.5s, clip-path 1s 0.5s;
  z-index: -999;

  &::before {
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    top: getsp375(92px);
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

&--link {
  padding: 0 15px;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out, transform 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  @include sp {
    border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: black;
  }
}

&--white {
  padding: 2px 15px;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out, transform 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  @include sp {
    border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: white;
  }
}

&--contact {
  display: none;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out, transform 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  @include sp {
    display: block;
    border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 3.5em;
    height: getsp375(156px);
    text-align: left;
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

}

This is the code for nav__btn

```
 &__btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: -200px;
  }
```

This is the code for slider

```
.slider {
top: 133px;
  @include sp {
    top: getsp375(88px);
    z-index: 999;
  }

  &__cell {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
    @include sp {
      bottom: getsp375(2px);
    }

    &--img {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      margin-right: 0;
      height: auto;
      @include sp {
        display: none;
      }
    }

    &--img-sp {
      display: none;
      @include sp {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
/**
 * Move the nav__links on the backwards first
 */

const links = document.getElementsByClassName('nav__links');
const btn = document.getElementsByClassName('nav__btn');
const container = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
const slider = document.getElementsByClassName('slider');

btn.forEach((elem) => {
   elem.onclick = () => {
     links.style.zIndex = links.style.zIndex === '999' ? '0' : '999';
     container.style.zIndex = container.style.zIndex === '-999' ? '0' : '-999';
     slider.style.zIndex = slider.style.zIndex === '-999' ? '0' : '-999';
   });
});
```

Assuming there is a class in the HTML called `nav__btn`, then this should work.

- Be aware that `id` is unique to one element, but many elements can have the same `class`. When selecting by `class` in JavaScript, you should expect that there will be more than one.
- When adding the `onclick` event handler, this must be done one element at a time (in plain JavaScript), so you need to loop through them.

Comment: It is still not working, https://ibb.co/k3p4qDd this is the output. The slider is still in the forward position when the nav__btn was toggled.

Comment: My post is already edited, I added the relevent codes.

Comment: It is still now working. The output is just the same. I guess I need to change the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an `HTMLCollection`, not a single element, so `btn.onclick` wouldn't be triggered, as `onclick` isn't being called on a single element, but an array. Similarly, when changing the z-index, you would need to do it for each element individually, as opposed to the entire collection, meaning you would need to loop through the `links`, `container` and `slider` HTMLCollections and apply the style individually.

Additionally, if you are using `document.getElementsByClassName`, then you should remove the period (.) from the strings, as that is only necessary when you are using one of the `querySelector` methods.

```
const links = document.getElementsByClassName('nav__links');

// Assuming there's only one button used to toggle
const btn = document.getElementsByClassName('nav__btn')[0];
const containers = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
const sliders = document.getElementsByClassName('slider');
    
btn.onclick = () => {
  for (let link of links) {
      link.style.zIndex = link.style.zIndex === '999' ? '' : '999';
  }
  for (let container of containers) {    
      container.style.zIndex = container.style.zIndex === '-999' ? '' : '-999';
  }
  for (let slider of sliders) {    
      slider.style.zIndex = slider.style.zIndex === '-999' ? '' : '-999';
  }
}
```

You can see the code in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/mgf70kwp/35/.

I added random HTML and CSS, and am outputting the current `z-index` value to the div as well so that you can see it toggling between the two values, though the code in this answer (not the jsfiddle) should be all you need to get the effect you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you catch an element by its class its properties remain in index `0`. So you can first set your container's `zIndex` with a number, then you can check and change that `zIndex` in this way:

```js
const container = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
const slider = document.getElementsByClassName('slider');
container[0].style.zIndex = "-999";

function changeZindex() {
    console.log(container[0].style.zIndex);
    container[0].style.zIndex = (container[0].style.zIndex === '-999') ? '1' : '-999';
}
```

```css
.container {
    background-color: #CCC;
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 3px;
}

.slider {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 3px;
}

.nav__btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 170px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Container</div>
<div class="slider">Slider</div>

<button class="nav__btn" onclick="changeZindex()">Press</button>
```

**`Update: Without using onclick property in the button`**

Just add click event listener like this `btn[index].addEventListener("click", function () {})` in this way:

```js
const container = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
const slider = document.getElementsByClassName('slider');
container[0].style.zIndex = "-999";

var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("nav__btn");  // this element contains just 1 DOM.

btn[0].addEventListener("click", function () {
    // console.log(container[0].style.zIndex);
    container[0].style.zIndex = (container[0].style.zIndex === '-999') ? '1' : '-999';
});
```

```css
.container {
    background-color: #CCC;
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 3px;
}

.slider {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 3px;
}

.nav__btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 170px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Container</div>
<div class="slider">Slider</div>

<button class="nav__btn">Press</button>
```

**`Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky).`**

Comment: Are there any ways to avoid onclick="changeZindex()? Like There's no js codes in html and all of the JS codes will be in JS files only.

Comment: @ErenHayashi, sure you can do that. Check my updated answer.